# long nominal group

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I am trying to translate this sentence:

> The public ASCAD database, which provides power consumption traces of a masked 128-bit AES implementation,...

like this:

> ASCAD öffentliche Datenbank, die Leistungsverläufe eines 128 bit maskierter AES Algorithmus ausführenden Gerätes zur Verfügung stellt,...

Is this correct?

EDIT:
I would like to know whether "die Leistungsverläufe eines 128 bit maskierter AES Algorithmus ausführenden Gerätes" correct ist.
Thanks.

EDIT2:
Ok, then a larger excerpt is the following:

> Recent publications, such as [8] and [9], exploit the advantages of deep-learning techniques in performing Side-Channel Attacks. One example of the Side-Channel community interest for such techniques is the release of the public ASCAD database, which provides power consumption traces of a masked 128-bit AES implementation, and is meant to be a common
>   benchmark to compare deep-learning techniques performances.

I have translated it like this:

> Neue wissenschaftliche Veröffentlichungen, wie z.B. [8] und [9], nutzen die Vorteile des Deep Learning aus, um Seitenkanalangrifen durchzuführen. ASCAD öffentliche Datenbank, die Verläufe der verbrauchten Leistung eines 128 bit maskierter AES Algorithmus ausführenden Gerätes zur Verfügung stellt, und die zum Ziel hat, ein gemeinsames Benchmark für Deep Learning Methoden zu bieten, zeigt die entstehende Interesse für solche Methoden.

Comment: consumption is missing. "die Verläufe der verbrauchten Leistung eines ..."

Comment: Welcome to German Language. No, your translation is not correct but we would need to know on which part of your sentence you have a doubt, and where we would just add some further improvements. Your title "long nominal group" does not reveal this.  Please [edit] your question and add more details. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. My question is about "Leistungsverläufe eines 128 bit maskierter AES Algorithmus ausführenden Gerätes". This is very long and not clear to me if all declensions are correct. What would be a appropriate title for this?

Comment: no it is not. This would be mistaken understood as "the amount of encryptions the unit is doing". (e.g. the unit doing many encrypts first, and less later) the DB is storing the power consumtion, to have a possible clue about what's encrypted, right?

Comment: Please provide more context, at least a whole paragraph. I understand what you are talking about, but not what the topic of this specific sentence is. Any guess about it makes a translation completely inaccurate.

Comment: The edit supplied additional information as requested by one comment, but moved further away from generic question (which Takkat commented even before the edit) towards an off-topic specific text translation.

Comment: Ok, a simple translation of the first question, which can be inserted in the whole sentence would be highly sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Die öffentliche ASCAD Datenbank enthält Stromverbrauchsprofile für maskierte AES128-Operationen.

*Leistung* in your attempt is misleading, since *power consumption* is best matched by *Stromverbrauch*. Note, that *implementation* means source code or executable code, which has no power consumption by itself; the power is consumed by the chip executing that implementation and depending on the chip and its settings the same implementation may have quite different power consumption.

Comment: Ok, but is it clear that AES128 means 128-bit key AES ?
"Implementation" might also designate a hardware implementation. Chips might be at hardware-level optimized for AES calculation (e.g. with a dedicated part)

Comment: @SomeWindowsUser: I accepted your edit even if I'm not convinced of it. For one, inserting the database name does not seem to add to the sentence structure; second, I did not want to provide a full translation, since the question is likely off-topic as it stands.

Comment: @GermanBeginner123: Yes, I consider AES128 ... AES256 as  self-explaining for everybody knowing what AES on its own means means.

Comment: @guidot I just thought that it might be better for an exact translation (or that you forgot it), but you have a valid point.